# Lost Chevalley Manuscript

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

In the end notes of chapter 9 in Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician", he mentions a lost Chevalley manuscript

> A systematic treatment of all possible properties of limits was contained in a manuscript by Chevalley on category theory; the manuscript was unfortunately lost by some shipping company.

Does anyone know if it was ever recovered or if the contents were reproduced in a subsequent text?

Comment: I think this is more appropriately asked at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It reminds me the footnote in the beginning of SGA 1 Chapter VI: it refers to a book in progress by Chevalley and Gabriel. It is said to be ready for the year 2000. Given the release date of  SGA 1, I'm pretty sure it is a joke because the manuscript were already lost. If it is the same book, then it is definitely lost...

Comment: I also read that end note and always found very very strange that Chevalley never bothered to rewrite the manuscript or keep a copy for himself.